# Node.js Error: Cannot find module 'ssl-root-cas/latest'

Tags: node.js, ssl

Working with Node.js (Version 8.2.1) and Express, I am running an SSL-secured webapp which was working fine, but all of a sudden I am getting this error regarding the "ssl-root-cas" module when trying to restart the application:

Error: Cannot find module 'ssl-root-cas/latest'

This is the code for including the ssl certificates into my Node.js/Express application:

```
var rootCas = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();

rootCas
  .addFile('../foo/foo.key')
  .addFile('../foo/foo.crt')
  ;

https.globalAgent.options.ca = rootCas;

rootCas.inject();
```

All I did was installing the "compression" module via NPM. Ever since this installation, I keep getting this error. Uninstalling the "compression" module, restarting the server, nothing worked out. Again, prior to installing the compression module, everything worked fine. Any ideas what might be the problem with the ssl-root-cas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the ssl module in your `package.json`? It's possible that installing the compression module wiped away dependencies in `node_modules` that weren't in the package file.

Comment: Sort of, but you put me on the right path. As it turned out, the installation of the compression module indeed somehow wiped quite a few other modules (not only ssl-root-cas) which I had to reinstall one by one. First time that happened to me. How is that even possible? Thanks anyways!